# Remove content of p tag

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to remove certain content from a `p` tag with JavaScript?

If I have 5 `p` tags with the strings `First note` all the way to `Fifth note`, I would like to loop through with `querySelectorAll` and then use the `remove` functionality to remove the string `note` from the `p` tags.

This is how far I have managed, but I lack the functionality to specify a string in the `p` tag to delete:

```
const pTag = document.querySelectorAll('p')
pTag.forEach(function (p) {
    p.remove()
})
```

Comment: please share the html

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach( p => p.textContent = p.textContent.replace(" note",'');`?

Comment: That worked out, there was a ) missing at the end :) Just understood from another post that remove doesn't work to delete part of a string, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `remove()` method to only remove part of the string. You can use the `replace()` method instead:

```js
const pTag = document.querySelectorAll('p');
pTag.forEach(function(p) {
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace('note', '');
});
```

```html
<p>This is the first note</p>
<p>This is the second note</p>
<p>This is the third note</p>
<p>This is the fourth note</p>
<p>This is the fifth note</p>
```